# How to access process.env variable from a script command

Tags: node.js, angular

i have an angular project. I want to build the project to be different depending on whether the process.env.NODE_ENV file is test or production.

Angular has a `ng build` command that you can tag with configuration to define whether the project should be built as "test" or "production". Instead of hard coding these values i want it to be based on the process.env variable.

How do i access this process.env.NODE_ENV variable within my package.json script command.

**npm run build**

```
"build": "ng build --configuration=process.env.NODE_ENV",
```

At the moment i get the following error

> Configuration 'NODE_ENV' could not be found in project 'demo'. Error:
>   Configuration 'NODE_ENV' could not be found in project 'demo'.

Comment: on linux you can use `$NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 1):

`NODE_ENV=prod npm run build`

This will set the environment variable in process.env so you can access anywhere in node.js script.

This way you can pass any value into `NODE_ENV` while running.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng build --configuration=$NODE_ENV
```

or

```
ng build --configuration=%NODE_ENV%
```

depending on your platform.

`process.env` is only accessible through a javascript file running on node.js, what you need here is to use the shell syntax

Comment: Depending on platform, i am using linux. So i need to use the first one?

The reason im doing this is because k8 sets the env variables whcih my container? should have access to these variables and therefore i can build either test or production

Comment: @Kay yes, first one is for linux/mac, second one for windows